# Tuning MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database

I am having a MySQL database which is running on a dedicated Ubuntu server having 2GB RAM and 500GB hard drive. I appreciate if anyone could help on fine tuning the database to increase the performance. Enhancements need to impact on CRUD tasks of the database, including procedure calls' and scheduled events' performances.

I have done searches on the web regarding this and found various mechanisms, tools and etc in various websites to do the job. But I need to know the proper way of escalating the performance (ex: execution time of an SQL query and etc) of a MySQL database itself without using any 3rd party tools or software. The database configurations which I am having are listed below.

```
MySQL version: 5.5
Used storage engine: MyISAM
Operating system: Ubuntu 12
Hard disk capacity: 500GB
RAM: 2GB
Other: The database consists of Tables, Indexes, Stored Procedures, Scheduled Events and Views
```

Answer (score 2):

You have said  nothing about the specifics of your data, its distribution, the type of workload you use, the ratio of reads to writes, the variety of your queries, the complexity of your queries, and so on. This is a vital part of the tuning process for one simple reason:

**Tuning is specific to your data and your workload.**

The guys who make database platforms such as MySQL pay a lot of attention to making sure the default settings are good enough for the majority of users. If there was some easy route to improving the performance of a database, they'd *already have done it at the factory*.

The guys who make the third party tools, on the other hand, write code that reads your data and your logs to find out information about your tables, their contents, and your queries, and that code makes best-guess estimates about tuning based on your data and your workload. They're not perfect, but they sure beat having to do that stuff manually if you don't know how to.

Think of tuning a database like tuning a guitar: You start with an idea of what you want (Standard tuning? Drop D? DADGAD?) and then you make small adjustments to one string at a time, measuring it against your desired result. Once you've achieved the best possible result for that string, you move onto the next one and make small changes there etc. When you get to the final string, you might have adjusted the balance of the whole guitar so you might have to revisit the settings from the beginning to make tiny incremental changes until the whole lot is singing perfectly.

Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-parameters.html to get started on the most important "strings" to tune in MySQL 5.5. There are lots, but none of them are particularly difficult on their own.

As a tangent, tuning your server away from the defaults *might* give you a 5-10% boost in performance. You'd be much better spending your time looking at your database design, data types, and the indexes you're using. You can often make 50%-100% improvements in performance by doing that sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @Jeremy. And if I say about the data distribution of the database, it is as follows. 
- Database is relational with normalized and de-normalized tables. Having One-to-One, One-to-Many, Many-to-One and Many-to-Many related data.
- Having 82 tables (could be expanded).
- I have connected this database to a web application. So, simultaneous DB calls will occur.
- Most of the queries consists of complex relationships which is having inner joins and outer joins, nested select statements, loops (in stored procedures), conditions, character encoding, type conversions and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should find http://www.mysqlcalculator.com/ helpful for starters.

This will show you some critical general defaults and allow you to 
enter your own values as displayed by
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES
to calculate MySQL maximum memory usage.

This will only scratch the surface - and will be enlightening.

There is NO simple answer.